# LazyInitializationException in playframework

Tags: java, playframework, lazy-initialization

while coding the Functional Test for my web app which uses `playframework`,I created

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    Fixtures.deleteDatabase();
}
@Test
public void testListTagged() {
    Fixtures.loadModels("data.yml");
    Response response = GET("/books/category/science");
    assertNotNull(renderArgs("books"));
    List<Book> books = (List<Book>)renderArgs("books");
    assertEquals(3,books.size());
```

the `listTagged` method checks the `Cache` for a map object (`String:List<Book>`)that contains a list of books belonging to the given category, and if the map is null or the list is null,database query is made  and the list is rendered as 'books'.

```
public static void listTagged(String category) {
        List<Book> books =null;
        Map<String,List<Book>> tagMap = (Map<String, List<Book>>) Cache.get("tagmap");
        if(tagMap!= null) {
            books = tagMap.get(category);           
        }

        if(tagMap==null || books == null) { 
            books= Book.findTaggedWith(category);
        }
        Book book = null;
        if (books!=null && books.size()>0) {
            book = books.get(0);
        }        
        render(category,book, books);
    }
```

Book class is

```
@Entity
public class Book extends Model implements Comparable<Book>{
    @Required
    @Column(unique = true)
    public String isbn;

    @Required
    //@Field
    public String name;
        ...
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    public Set<Category> categories;
    public Book(String isbn, String name, ...) {
        super();

        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.name = name;
        ...
        this.categories = new TreeSet<Category>();
    }
        ...
public static List<Book> findTaggedWith(String categoryName) {
        Map<String,List<Book>> tagMap = (Map<String, List<Book>>) Cache.get("tagmap");
        if(tagMap==null) {
            tagMap= new HashMap<String,List<Book>>();
        }
        List<Book> books = Book.find("select distinct book from Book book join book.categories as cat where cat.name=:name").bind("name", categoryName).fetch();
        tagMap.put(categoryName, books);
        Cache.add("tagmap", tagMap,"20mn");
        return books;
    }
```

Running the above test alone caused no problems.But when it was run along with some unit tests which called the database for various books causes a lazy initialization exception

```
A java.lang.RuntimeException has been caught, java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: play.exceptions.TemplateExecutionException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: models.Book.categories, no session or session was closed
```

How do I solve this? can someone please advise?

Answer (score 1):

you could use:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
public Set<Category> categories;
```

This will probably solve the problem. Otherwise you'll have to take care, that a session is open.  Tested and now working

Comment: thanks for the reply..putting fetch=fetchType.EAGER doesn't solve it..Since these are separate unit tests, how do I keep the session open?

Comment: I haven't worked with playframework yet, but the session of the entityManger is not available at the time you want to access the categories. Thus the categories can't be fetched. Normally EAGER should cause the Categories to be fetched together with Books. Just a guess: Maybe use something other than "Cache.get()"